# getting apache to run python on a mac

Tags: python, apache, macos, macports, apache-modules

So i have a new mac and i'm trying to get it to run apache with mod_python, mod_wsgi, and django.  I have a test test.py that simply contains: 
`#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"
print "Test Page"
print "</body></html>"`

I've just downloaded xcode4, used macports to install apache, php5, and mod_wsgi via the step provided on these sites:
http://www.phpied.com/installing-php-and-apache-on-mac-osx-that-was-pretty-easy/
http://heisel.org/blog/2009/09/25/mod-wsgi-mac/
for some reason mod_python wouldn't work so i downloaded the latest source code from the svn and doing the standard `./configure --with-apxs=/opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs
make
sudo make install`

and then configuring httpd.conf with the LoadModule blah modules/blah.so

when i started up apache with

```
sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/apache2.wrapper start
```

and navigated to test.py in my browser and I saw the entire file in plain text with i know that isn't right.
I turned on python debug in httpd.conf and saw this when i navigated to test.py again this popped out:

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      93626
Interpreter:    'dfelsmanmpx6.blah.blah'

ServerName:     'dfelsmanmpx6.blah.blah'
DocumentRoot:   '/Users/me/folder/workspace/'

URI:            '/test.py'
Location:       None
Directory:      '/'
Filename:       '/Users/me/folder/workspace/test.py'
PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'text'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1202, in _process_target
    module = import_module(module_name, path=path)

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 304, in import_module
    return __import__(module_name, {}, {}, ['*'])

ImportError: No module named text
```

anyone know what is wrong or know of a tutorial on how to do this on a mac with xcode 4(yes, in my research that is actually relevant since xcode 4 did away with some architecture support and thus rendered some modules outdated)?

Comment: [Don't use mod_python.](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html)

Comment: how would i do this without mod_python?, just getting test.py to run in apache that is.

Comment: Either use CGI or write a WSGI script.

Comment: I use gunicorn there are various options for WSGI options…

Answer (score 0):

As @ignatio-vazquez-abrams noted, mod_python is deprecated, but if you're set on using it, you may want to check out [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Once Homebrew is installed, you can run `brew install mod_python` in Terminal. After installation, you'll see a note about adding the compiled mod to your Apache config (as well as a deprecation warning.)

Comment: How would i do this without using mod_python then?